# Generalized "Duality" of Classical Propositional Logical Operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, propositional-calculus

Duality in propositional logic between conjunction and disjunction, $K$ and $A$ means that for any "identity", such as $KpNp = 0$ (ignoring the detail of how to define this notion in propositional logic), if we replace all instances of $K$ by $A$, all instances of $A$ by $K$, all instances of 1 by 0, and all instances of 0 by 1, the resulting equation will also consists of an "identity", $ApNp = 1$.  Suppose that instead of conjunction "$K$" and disjunction "$A$", we consider any pair of "dual" operations $\{Y, Z\}$ of the 16 logical operations such that they qualify as isomorphic via the negation operation $N$, where $Y$ does not equal $Z$.  By "isomorphic" I mean that the sub-systems $(Y, \{0, 1\})$, $(Z, \{0, 1\})$ are isomorphic in the usual way via the negation operation $N$, for example $K$ and $A$ qualify as "isomorphic" in the sense I've used it here.

If we have an identity involving operations $A_1, \dots, A_x$, and replace each instance of each operation by its "dual" $A'_1$, ..., $A'_x$, replace each instance of 1 by 0, and each instance of 0 by 1, is the resulting equation also an identity?  If so, how does one prove this?  How does one show that the equation obtained via the "duality" transformation here is also an identity?

Comment: Every time one uses non-standard notation, it is good practice to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

The resulting equation *is* also an identity.  This is because any of the $16$ operations can be put in canonical disjunctive normal form using only $\land$, $\lor$, and $\lnot$.  Then the replacement procedure described in the post becomes  the standard one, and we are dealing with ordinary duality.

Comment: Do we need dnfs here?

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood: Probably not. But they are a codification of the truth-table, and like the mathematician of the joke, I reduced the problem to one already solved.

Comment: I don't see why you've said "isomorphisms".  There exists only one relevant isomorphism here, and it's the negation operation.

Comment: I don't think of it as an isomorphism. An isomorphism preserves the operations.

Comment: Huh? Negation "preserves", if you must use that term, conjunction when going from ({0, 1}, K) to ({0, 1}, A), and "preserves" disjunction when going from ({0, 1}, A) to ({0, 1}, K)... it consists of a bijective map H: H(x +$_1$ y)=(H(x) +$_2$ H(y)), where "+$_1$" and "+$_2$" indicate distinct members of {K, A}, since the De Morgan laws hold. I don't know what you mean by "isomorphisms" in this post.